# Creating transaction with using blockcypher

Tags: transactions

> [https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/new?token={{TOKEN}}](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/new?token=%7B%7BTOKEN%7D%7D)
>
> To use BlockCypher's two-endpoint transaction creation tool, first you
> need to provide the input address(es), output address, and value to
> transfer (in satoshis). Provide this in a partially-filled out TX
> request object.

From where can I get input addresses to create transaction?

Answer (score 2):

It's simply the address(es) that you want to send Bitcoins from.

Comment: I thought these were the addresses from which input transactions were sent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the Address API with the [Address Balance Endpoint](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#address-balance-endpoint). If you set the flag *unspentOnly* to *true* the response will only include unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs). Once you have a list of unspent transaction outputs you could use them as input for [Create Transaction Call](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#creating-transactions). I hope this helps.